# Java null String equals result

Tags: java, string, null, equals

Please help me how does the string.equals in java work with null value? Is there some problem with exceptions?
Three cases:

```
boolean result1,result2, result3;

    //1st case
    String string1 = null;
    String string2 = null;
    result = string1.equals(string2);
    //2nd case
    String string1 = "something";
    String string2 = null;
    result2 = string1.equals(string2);
    //3rd case 
    String string1 = null;
    String string2 = "something";
    result3 = string1.equals(string2);
```

What the values of results are? I expect this values:

> result1 is true;
>   result2 is false;
>   result3 is false;

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I'm not sure about case #2, but case 1 and 3 will trigger a Null Exception since you are trycing to call a methond of a null object.

Comment: You can try and answer your own question.

Comment: @ChrisThompson not exactly what happens in this case but I compare a lot of strings in my work for school so I needed know behaviour of this cases and I don't want to miss something ..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You cannot use the dereference (dot, '.') operator to access instance variables or call methods on an instance if that instance is `null`. Doing so will yield a `NullPointerException`.

It is common practice to use something you know to be non-null for string comparison. For example, `"something".equals(stringThatMayBeNull)`.

Comment: Not completely true. You can invoke a static method on a null reference.

Comment: Ok thats what I needed to know, thanks. I'll use empty strings "" instead of null string :-)

Comment: @user1097772 Empty strings are not equal to null.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes I know that. I mean that I'll not use the null strings but empty strings. The values of string1 and string2 in my example are results from my parser ... I'll ensure not null strings and I'll have no problem. Empty values will be represented by empty string instead of null string.

Answer (score 24):

Use `Objects.equals()` to compare strings, or any other objects if you're using JDK 7 or later. It will handle nulls without throwing exceptions. See more here: [how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

And if you're not running JDK 7 or later you can copy the `equals` method from `Objects` like this:

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Comment: While the example of `"a string literal".equals(someStringVariable)` in the accepted answer is to be commended, that doesn't help OP figure out how to handle the case where both strings are null (despite that being the first case OP presented).  This is the best answer, as it handles all 3 cases without using custom code or a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 12):

Indeed, you cannot use the dot operator on a `null` variable to call a non static method.

Despite this, all depends on overriding the `equals()` method of the `Object` class. In the case of the `String` class, is:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you pass `null` as parameter, both "if" will fail, returning `false`;

An alternative for your case is to build a method for your requirements:

```
public static boolean myEquals(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1 == null)
        return s2 == null;
    return s1.equals(s2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That piece of code will throw a `NullPointerException` whenever string1 is null and you invoke `equals` on it, as is the case when a method is implicitly invoked on any null object.

To check if a string is null, use `==` rather than `equals`.

Although `result1` and `result3` will not be set due to NullPointerExceptions, result2 would be false (if you ran it outside the context of the other results).

Answer (score 2):

To prevent NPE while comparing Strings if at least one of them can be null, use StringUtils.equals method which is null-safe.

Answer (score 2):

I am late to answer this, but you can use

```
StringUtils.equals(str1, str2)
```

if you are using spring

Answer (score 1):

You will get a NullPointerException in case 1 and case 3.

You cannot call any methods (like `equals()`) on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use dot operator with null since doing so will give NullPointerException. Therefore we can take advantage of try..catch block in our program. This is a very crude way of solving your problem, but you will get desired output.

```
try {
   result = string1.equals(string2);
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
   result = string2 == null; //This code will be executed only when string 1 is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Our most common use-case of this type of thing is when we have a database field that contains "Y" or "N" to represent a Boolean (it's an old system, don't ask).

Thus, we do this:

`if ("Y".equals(stringObjectThatMayBeNull) ? result : otherResult);`

Instead of this:

`if (stringObjectThatMayBeNull.equals("Y") ? result : otherResult);`

... which avoids a NullPointerException when executing the .equals method.